# How to add an environment scoped variable in the VSTS release definition editor?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have several existing VSTS release definitions; each definition only has a single environment. I now want to add a second environment to one of the definitions, so I need environment specific variables for each environment in the release definition, e.g., to set the server to deploy to. If I go into the Variables tab in the release editor, I have a number of Process Variables listed with a Scope of "Release". I can drop down the Scope field for a variable and it shows the following items in the drop down:

```
Release
Env1
Env2
```

Where Env1 and Env2 are the names of my two environments in this release definition. (I don't know where it got "Release" from). I click on Env1 to try and set this variable to be only used by the Env1 deployment, but the field immediately reverts to Release. There does not seem to be anyway to change the scope of a variable to be specific to an environment. I have also tried adding a new variable, but it always forces the Scope to "Release".

If I am missing something in the editor it does not seem obvious.

Edit: the problem happens with the "new" release editor in VSTS. If I use the old editor, then next to the environment name is "...". If I click on that I get an option to "Configure variables", which allows me to add an environment scoped variable. I can then see the new variable in the correct scope even when using the new editor. What I can't find is any way to add environment scoped variables in the new editor. Is this a bug with the new editor?

Edit2: the problem described happens when using IE11, but not Chrome!

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: So @DanielMann, I am trying to set a environment-scoped variable in the correct way, but it is not working for some reason?

Comment: Added an edit to my question.

Comment: I can't repro the issue with either editor.

Comment: Added Edit2. The problem seems to be specific to IE11, and not Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with the release definition editor in IE11. I'd use the "Report a Problem" link and open an issue. In the interim, use a different browser -- Chrome and Edge both work well.